# ASyncTask modifying variable on main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Let me first provide a bit of background. I am creating an Activity that, on create, will call an ASyncTask to retrieve a list of Cholesterol data. This ASyncTask is a private class within my Activity. Everything is working properly, however, I would like to be able to store my results back in the Activity after it is done. This way, every time Cholestoral data is added in the Activity, I will only have to make one call to append the data, not to re-list the whole thing.

So, my question is: how would I set up the onPostExecute to modify my field in the MainActivity? **Right now what is happening is, it gets through the whole background task, correctly populates the temporary list, returns Success and then seems to never make it to the onPostExecute() where I copy the temporary List into my Main Activity list.**

I pasted the source below, I apologize if it is a bit messy. I reused a bit from previous activities.

```
public class CholestoralActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public GraphView graph;
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
public ArrayList<CholesterolInformation> cholesterolInformationList;

public void setCholesterolInformationList(ArrayList<CholesterolInformation> cholesterolInformationList) {
    this.cholesterolInformationList = cholesterolInformationList;
}

//TODO: Populate ArrayList given JSON response, and call generateDataPoints()
private class ListCholestoralAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ArrayList<CholesterolInformation> tmpcholesterolInformationList;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        tmpcholesterolInformationList = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpcholesterolInformationList.clear();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");
        String listURL = params[0];
        listURL += email;
        URL url = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(listURL);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            result = response.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        try {
            JSONObject listObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = listObject.optJSONArray("cholesterol");
            if (jsonArray != null) {
                for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                    CholesterolInformation cholesterolInformation = new CholesterolInformation();
                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        String HDL = jsonObject.getString("hdl");
                        double hdl = Double.parseDouble(HDL);
                        String LDL = jsonObject.getString("ldl");
                        double ldl = Double.parseDouble(LDL);
                        String triGlyceride = jsonObject.getString("triGlycaride");
                        double tri = Double.parseDouble(triGlyceride);
                        String date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                        String unit = jsonObject.getString("unit");
                        cholesterolInformation.setDate(date);
                        cholesterolInformation.setHdl(hdl);
                        cholesterolInformation.setLdl(ldl);
                        cholesterolInformation.setTriGlycaride(tri);
                        cholesterolInformation.setUnit(unit);
                        tmpcholesterolInformationList.add(cholesterolInformation);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return "Success";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if ("Success".equals(result)) {
            System.out.println("Successfully populated list.");
            setCholesterolInformationList(tmpcholesterolInformationList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you log the value of result and let us know what do you get?

Comment: Yep, I just paused the debugger on the "if" statement in onPostExecute, and result contains "Success" and the temporary list has the correct information within it.

Comment: And method `setCholesterolInformationList` is getting called?

Comment: setCholestoralInformationList IS being called, and no cholesterolInformationList is an ArrayList of POJO objects that will later be used to display data on a Graph.

Comment: I am thinking maybe I should just call the methods to `generateDataPoints()` and `initializeGraph()` right after I call the setter in the `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: I can see that setting temp array list to the class member should work fine. I guess you are not using it after its being populated

Answer (score 0):

if your AsyncTask is a private class in your activity you can acces variables in you Activity class

so

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        myTextViewWhichIsInActivity.setText(result);
  }
```

Have you logged 'result' try

```
  Log.i(TAG,"result is ["+result+"] is the same as Success");
```

this way you can be sure you dont have any trailing spaces or rogue typos, it is always better to parse integers as they are less prone to errors than strings